# Upgrade Macbook Pro from 10.6.8 to 10.8

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, upgrade

I am considering upgrading my Macbook Pro with 2GB of memory from 10.6.8 to 10.8 (Mountain Lion).

Are there any other considerations for upgrading?
Is this generally a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

This is a somewhat subjective question. I would personally recommend upgrading to 8 GB of memory and an SSD, but since you're still within the boundaries of the minimum specs, there's no definitive answer. Outside of making sure that all the software you'll need to have working will work, you don't really need to consider anything. I would personally recommend upgrading to Mavericks as it's better supported and optimized then Mountain Lion, and El Cap is not out of the question either.

Comment: I didn't know upgrading to Mavericks was an option. Thanks, I'll look into that.

Comment: @AlLelopath To my knowledge, all Macs that support Mountain Lion support Mavericks and above.

Comment: Personally, I would go with El Capitan. I hate running old software.

Comment: Could old hw run El Capitan efficiently?

Comment: What is the model/year of the MBP computer? The is no point in offering solutions until one can determine what options are available.