# Want to update from OSX 10.6.8 to OSX 10.9

Tags: software-update

When I go into my apple software updates on my OSX 10.6.8 computer to update to an OSX 10.9, the computer tells me that I do not have any new updates. How can I update to OSX 10.9 if it does not give me that option?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) For us to be able to help you, you're really going to need to provide some more details. You can do this by editing your question. As a minimum we really need to know the exact model of your computer? You can get this by going to Apple > About This Mac. This will provide a description of your hardware, so providing those details is crucial because, as it stands, we don't even know if your computer is compatible with OS X 10.9. Also, it may be worth providing some context as to why you need to upgrade (in case we can provide an alternative option).

Comment: Lots of potential leads here. Search for lion and Snow Leopard - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80680/installing-running-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion-from-an-external-hard-drive-onto-my

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS X Lion - 10.7 was (is) a paid upgrade. From there, you can then ride the free major upgrade train as far as your hardware allows.

- [Upgrade Macbook Pro from 10.6.8 to 10.8](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/227131/)

I’ve heard of people jumping to ElCapitan, but never experienced it since I have lion digitally as well as on a USB key so I just rolled that path in the past.

- [Upgrade iMac12,2 from Mac OS X 10.6.8](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/320924/)

You may run into issues, so feel free to ask a specific question if you run into a specific block knowing you can’t just upgrade in one step.